# Qual a regra que rege a acentuação da palavra "português"?

Tags: ortografia, acentuação

Enquanto estudava regras de acentuação, não encontrei qual a regra capaz de explicar a acentuação da palavra *português*.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Se não pusesses acento ficaria *portugues*, que rimaria com *alugues*, com em "preciso que tu alugues uma casa".

Comment: A dúvida foi causada pela presença do *-u-* (*-guês*). Poderia ser alguma das regras de ditongos.

Comment: GR, o *-uê-* de *português* não é ditongo, e o *-ue* de *alugues* também não. Em ambos os casos, o *u* não se lê; está lá só porque *portugês* se leria como *portujês*. Só é ditongo quando as duas vogais são pronunciadas (juntamente), como por exemplo *ag**uen**tar*.

Comment: O _-u-_ em _português_ seria, então, semivogal, correto? Assim como em _alugues_ e _freguês_. É isso?

Comment: Não, semivogal é um som que se liga a outra vogal para formar um ditongo (ou tritongo), como o som de *u* em *pau, seu, água,* e o som de *i* em *pai, lei*; depois o som de *i* e *e* em *próprio, veado* depende (vê a resposta à tua outra pergunta) uns classificam-no semivogal que forma ditongo; outros como vogal separado por hiato da outra vogal. O *u* de *freguês*, etc. é uma letra vogal muda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade a regra é simples e bem conhecida - o conceito chave que talvez tenha faltado na sua busca foi o da *tonicidade*, ou *sílaba forte*, da palavra, porque "português" é uma *oxítona*, ou seja, tem a última sílaba pronunciada com mais ênfase, e é nisso que se baseia a regra de acentuação relevante, como colocam, entre outros, o [Norma Culta](https://www.normaculta.com.br/palavras-oxitonas/), o [Mundo Educação](https://mundoeducacao.bol.uol.com.br/gramatica/acentuacao-no-novo-acordo-ortografico.htm) e o [LPeU](http://www.lpeu.com.br/q/g574h):

> **Oxítonas**
>
> Recebem acento agudo ou circunflexo as palavras oxítonas terminadas das em 'a', 'e' ou 'o', seguidas ou não de 's':
>
> Aguarrás, aliás, após, até, atrás, através, avó, Carajás, cajá, chá, Barnabé, café, crachá, dominó, está, gás, Inês, invés, já, jiló, olá,olé, paletó, pontapé, Queirós,retrós, revés, sabiá, Tomás etc.
>       Bambolê, camelô, cortês, frapê, Inês, javanês, nenê, polonês, **português** etc.

Comment: Então `português`, `até`, `roubá-las` e `gigolô` são todas acentuadas por serem terminadas em `a`, `e` ou `o` seguidos ou não de `s`?

Comment: @GRSousaJr Isso.